# Compile errors from Qt 5.11.1 on centos 7

Tags: c++, qt

Installing Qt 5.11.1 opensource on centos 7. I received the following error:

```
qwaylanddisplay.cpp: In member function ‘void QtWaylandClient::QWaylandDisplay::addRegistryListener(QtWaylandClient::RegistryListener, void*)’:
qwaylanddisplay.cpp:315:35: error: could not convert ‘{listener, data}’ from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘QtWaylandClient::QWaylandDisplay::Listener’
     Listener l = { listener, data };
                                   ^
make[3]: *** [.obj/qwaylanddisplay.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/opt/Qt5.11.1/5.11.1/Src/qtwayland/src/client'
make[2]: *** [sub-client-make_first] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/opt/Qt5.11.1/5.11.1/Src/qtwayland/src'
make[1]: *** [sub-src-make_first] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/opt/Qt5.11.1/5.11.1/Src/qtwayland'
make: *** [module-qtwayland-make_first] Error 2
```

This is a new system with initial installation.  Am I missing a library or is this actually a problem with Qt?

thanks,
jerry

Comment: Could be a too old compiler.

Comment: Well the compiler is 4.8.5-28. Just went through an update and it remained the same.

Comment: May be you need to switch on C++11 functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, 4.8.5-28 sounds like too old *gcc* version. You may need to switch to a Qt version a few steps older. Read the Qt release notes for versions going back from 5.11 to find the one which started to require full C++11. If you want to write applications compatible with stock Centos 7, I would stick with whatever Qt version it provides (much less files you need to deploy yourself).

But if you want the latest version, then you either need to install a new enough compiler, or you need to run another OS (recent Fedora for you maybe?) in a VM (Virtualbox probably) or a container (Docker probably, though then you have to jump through an extra hoop or two to get X11 GUI on your screen).

Comment: thanks!  Just getting back to this. I installed QT 5.11.1 on Fedora at work with out any problems. Will change that here and go forward.